# convert trans-sql to LINQ LEFT JOIN and Where Clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How would you convert this trans-sql to LINQ?

I've tried it with the DefaultIfEmpty() but it seems to not be working for me.
Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT s.Status 
FROM EducationModule M 
     LEFT JOIN EducationModuleStatus S ON  M.CourseID = S.CourseID 
               AND M.ModuleID = S.ModuleID 
               AND S.StudentID = '1506' 
WHERE M.courseid = 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Joining on multiple columns in Linq to SQL is a little different.
You have to take advantage of anonymous types and compose a type for the multiple columns you wish to compare against, and under the sheet this will generate the type of join you are looking for.

```
var abcd = from tl in db.EducationModule
            join s  in db.EducationModuleStatus 
            on new { t1.CourseID, t1.ModuleID } equals new {s.CourseID, s.ModuleID}    
            into tl_s
            where tl.CourseID == 2 AND s.StudentID == '1506'     
            from s in tl_s.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
               Status = s.Status
             };
```